# Output for components.minutes unexpected. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am trying to get the current hour and minute of the day using the following code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: NSDate())

// Concatenate time and minutes together
let hour = components.hour
let minute = components.minute

println(components.hour)
println(components.minute)
```

The output for both:

```
components.hour output: 0
components.minute output: 9223372036854775807
```

It is currently 00.30 where I am. But why does `components.minute` print such a long number that doesn't to me seem to be the minute 30.

Also if anyone can suggest another way of getting the current time as e.g. `13:00`?

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: You only asked for `.CalendarUnitHour` so why are you worried about what minute was? Include `.CalendarUnitMinute` if you want minute, too.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what I must have done, I must have accidentally removed '.CalendarUnitMinute', I did have it in there before. Yes this fixed it thank you.

Comment: Just want to point out Timepiece for working with dates in Swift. https://github.com/naoty/Timepiece

Answer (score 1):

`9223372036854775807` is [`NSUndefinedDateComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSDateComponents_undefined_component_identifier) value. This means that `NSDateComponents` object doesn't have the value.

You have to join desired `NSCalendarUnit`s with `|`:

```
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: NSDate())
```

OR, from iOS 8, we have handy `component(_:fromDate:)` method to get just one component's value.

```
let now = NSDate()
let hour = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: now)
let minute = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: now)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a sane answer to this question.